# How to get current tenant when using Appartment gem in multi-tenancy Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, database-schema, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

How can I find out which tenant (schema) is the current one when Apartment was initialized according to request

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> Apartment::Tenant.current

P. S. Thank you @pa-buisson

Comment: Beware, ``Apartment::Database`` seems to be deprecated now. Instead, you can now use ``Apartment::Tenant.current``.

Comment: Is possible that current is returning always public?

Comment: Note that this returns a `String` with the current subdomain, not a `Tenant` object.

Comment: @Sergiy Seleskyy Is it is possible to get Tenant based on a given record. For example user1 is in tenent1 and user2 is in tenent2.  How can I find Tenent of user1

Apartment::Tenant.current(user1)  ??

Comment: @Ronats thank you for your question. Unfortunately, I cannot help you now. 8 years have passed since I had been working with that domain.